# Joomla! 2.5.28 Текущая дата в HTML-моудле

Tags: php, веб-программирование, joomla

Всем привет!

Есть простой HTML модуль, с ценами и текущей датой сверху, пытаюсь в

```
<td class="current_date"></td>
```

вывести текущую дату методом:

```
<?php echo date("d.m.Y"); ?>
```

Не работает. Погуглив выяснил, что в модуле HTML только HTML возможен.

Получается, это можно сделать только в модуле шаблона сайта?
Как с помощью PHP, и возможно ли сиё вообще, "выцепить" тэг  по классу "date" и воткнуть туда текущую дату? Без JavaScript. И в каком месте шаблона прописывать, до тэга или после? Причем в шаблоне то прописано так:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="prices" />
```

Спасибо!

Решил так:
В шаблон перед тэгом `</body>` добавил:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var d=new Date();
var day=(d.getDate());
var month=d.getMonth() + 1;
var year=d.getFullYear();

var tds = document.getElementById("current_date");

day = (day < 10) ? '0'+day : day;
month = (month < 10) ? '0'+month : month;

tds.innerHTML=day + "." + month + "." + year;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> в модуле HTML только HTML возможен

Да, это так.

В данной ситуации лично я вижу два варианта:

- Поискать готовый модуль с поддержкой выполнения PHP (имхо, занятие мало перспективное);
- Написать собственный модуль.

Comment: А в шаблоне никак? Ну хорошо, пускай JavaScript, всё равно - нет?
JS то будет исполняться на клиенте , а там уже будет не
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="prices" />, а HTML

Comment: Вставлять такие вещи в шаблон, это тот ещё костыль. А, JavaScript выведет дату и время на компе посетителя сайта. Оно может быть не синхронизировано с сервером времени (читайте выставлено не правильно). Да и часовые пояса никто не отменял.

Comment: Streletz, это всё понятно. Но сайт узкоспециализированный по конкретному городу и его области, о чем написано на главной странице. Да и вообще, ну у нас 5-е число и цена 1000 денег. А у посетителя 8-е число на компе. И что? Цену то ему все равно актуальную покажет )) Это просто вывод инфы на странице, а не прайс для скачивания и т.п. В общем сделал так.(добавил в сабж)

Comment: Ну что же, Вам виднее.